# OpenGL Perspective matrices not working

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glsl

I'm new to both stack overflow and OpenGL. 
I'm trying to create my first little 3d program with custom shaders, but i have a problem with the various matrices that are required. I don't know exactly what causes complete black screen, if it is that i load uniforms incorrectly or that I'm failing at calculating the matrices. Anyway, I post the code down here and if anyone can help it would be amazing. 
**Main Cpp file**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\glut.h>
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
#include <glm\vec3.hpp>
#include <glm\mat4x4.hpp>
#include <glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm\gtc\type_ptr.hpp>

GLuint programID, vbo;

using namespace glm;
void loadShaders(){
    char vertex_file_path[] = "vertex.glsl";
char fragment_file_path[] = "fragment.glsl";
// Create the shaders
GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

// Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
std::string VertexShaderCode;
std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path);
if (VertexShaderStream.is_open()){
    std::string Line = "";
    while (std::getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
        VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    VertexShaderStream.close();

}
else{
    printf("Impossible to open %s. Are you in the right directory ? Don't forget to read the FAQ !\n", vertex_file_path);
    getchar();
    throw new std::runtime_error("Shaders not found");
}

// Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
std::string FragmentShaderCode;
std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
if (FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
    std::string Line = "";
    while (std::getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
        FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    FragmentShaderStream.close();
}

GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
int InfoLogLength;
// Compile Vertex Shader
printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer, NULL);
glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

// Check Vertex Shader
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
if (Result == GL_FALSE){
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    char * VertexShaderErrorMessage = new char[InfoLogLength + 1];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, VertexShaderErrorMessage);
    std::cout << VertexShaderErrorMessage << std::endl;
    printf("Could not compile vertex shader: %s\n", VertexShaderErrorMessage);
    getchar();
    throw new std::runtime_error("Could not compile vertex shader");
}

// Compile Fragment Shader
std::cout << "Compiling shader : " << fragment_file_path << std::endl;
char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer, NULL);
glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

// Check Fragment Shader
glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
if (Result == GL_FALSE){
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    char * FragmentShaderErrorMessage = new char[InfoLogLength + 1];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, FragmentShaderErrorMessage);
    printf("Could not compile fragment shader: %s\n", FragmentShaderErrorMessage);
    getchar();
    throw new std::runtime_error("Could not compile fragment shader");
}

// Link the program
printf("Linking program\n");
GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

// Check the program
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
if (Result == GL_FALSE){
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength + 1);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    printf("%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    throw new std::runtime_error("Could not compile program");
}

glDetachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
glDetachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);

glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

programID = ProgramID;
}

void loadMatrices(){
GLuint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "model");
GLuint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "view");
GLuint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "projection");

mat4 model = scale(mat4(1.0f), vec3(1.0f));
mat4 view = lookAt(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f), vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
mat4 projection = perspective(45.0f, 16.0f / 9.0f, 0.01f,  100.0f);

glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(model));
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(view));
glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(projection));
}

void renderLoop(){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(programID);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    0,
    3,
    GL_FLOAT,
    GL_FALSE,
    0,
    (void *) 0
);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glutSwapBuffers();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

int MY_ZERO = 0;
glutInit(&MY_ZERO, NULL);
glutInitWindowSize(1280, 720);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOBULE);
glutCreateWindow("Test");
glewExperimental = true;
glewInit();
glutIdleFunc(renderLoop);
glutDisplayFunc(renderLoop);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  // Nice perspective corrections
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
gluPerspective(75.0f, 16.0f / 9, 0.1f, 100.0f);
std::cout << "Setting blendFunc..." << std::endl;
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
loadShaders();
loadMatrices();
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

float vals[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f, -10.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, -10.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f
};

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vals), vals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glutMainLoop();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

**Vertex Shader**

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main(){
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(pos, 1.0f);
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: `glutSwapBuffers();` swaps the buffers, you need to ask glut for double buffering in main by a call to`glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE)`.

Comment: this dosen't fix my issue but this helps anyway, thanks.

Comment: glm expects angles in degrees in the `perspective` function. (unless you define somewhere `GLM_FORCE_RADIANS`)

Comment: sorry for the many little mistakes, but I had radians in there just for testing and forgot to remove it, but no clues on big mistakes that compromise everything?

Comment: `GLUT_DOBULE` looks wrong to me. And you are mixing fixed function code with core code. What are the `glMatrixMode` calls made for? If this is a core profile (which I cannot tell since you don't specify that), a VAO is required to draw. And you are never checking whether any OpenGL errors happend.

Comment: Thanks man, turns out I am not loading the matrices in the uniform correctly, I'll continue to investigate. Also, added VAO and checked for errors.

Comment: Also, the glMatrixMode stuff is for test, to see if the triangle renders woth defailt shaders.

Comment: But better comment out such "test" stuff before you present your code to others. And that it is still active in the code may also be one reason for the mistake  that you did not use the matrices in the vertex shader.

Answer (score 1):

There are several general aspects of the code which need improvement; e.g.

⊗ it can throw but doesn't `catch` and cleanup:

```
// there's no try/catch block enclosing this
throw new std::runtime_error("Could not compile vertex shader");
```

⊗ it's ready to leak:

```
char * VertexShaderErrorMessage = new char[InfoLogLength + 1];
/* ... */
throw new std::runtime_error("Could not compile vertex shader");
```

⊗ it [needlessly](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node63.html) consumes CPU and GPU  time

```
glutIdleFunc(renderLoop); // boosts the frame rate for performance
                          // meters only
```

and so on, e.g. unrolling the shader creation and error handling loop violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

---

From an **OpenGL**-specific pov, there are several things which are not ok.

⊗ This

```
mat4 view = lookAt(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f),
                   vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 
                   vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

(rightfully) prepares to step back back 2 units with the cam; but that matrix is not used in the shader

```
void main(){
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(pos, 1.0f);
}
```

⊗ The shaders are first created and attached to the program, but on success deleted and detached again from the program which is intended to be used

```
glDetachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
glDetachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);

glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);
```

⊗ These calls

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
/* ... */
gluPerspective(75.0f, 16.0f / 9, 0.1f, 100.0f);
/* ... */
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

are meant for the (deprecated) fixed pipeline; which is not used here, and

⊗ there is no [glClear()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glClear.xhtml) call in the code

There may be more things to attend to, but this is what I see on the first look.

We can have a deeper look into the code it if those things are dealt with first.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

The problem was that I wasn't using the program that holds the uniforms, so it failed to load them. Thanks to @BDL I started watching for OpenGL errors and i found GL_INVALID_OPERATION after every `glUniformMatrix4fv`. Poor debugging on my part. Thanks to everyone that helped

**TL;DR** put `glUseProgram(program)` before any `glUniformMatrix4fv()`